# Add a random SKSpriteNode to the scene

Tags: ios, objective-c, sprite-kit

I have a method for each object (`SKSpriteNode`) in which I set it's image, position, name etc.
This gets added to the scene at a random point in time. Because there are a lot of objects this results in way too much code.

It works, but I would prefer to have just one method that adds a random SKSpriteNode at a random point in time to the scene. I guess I would also need another Method that defines all the SKSpriteNodes with their images and other settings.

I've been trying to make an array of all the objects and have a method choose a random object out of that array and add it to the scene, but I can't get it to work.

EDIT:
Sorry, for not being specific enough. If adding the objects to an array is the best way to add a random object to the scene, my question would be how to make an array with those SKSpriteNodes. If using an array is not the way to go, how do I create a random Node and at it to the scene at a random point in time?

Comment: What's the question here? Are you asking how to write a function to create a random node and add it at a random point in the scene?

Comment: What exactly can't you get to work? This is too broad to answer at the moment.

Comment: Is the issue in getting the random spriteNode from array?

Comment: Please return the question to the previous state so that my answer remains correct, and create new question for your next problem :)
Now to answer the issue you have at the moment, it would be best to simply make a switch case based on a random number that would ether create rock or crate and place them on random location. There is no need to create both and place them in the array.

Comment: That was actually my first question. As you can see in my first edit: 'If using an array is not the way to go, how do I create a random node and add it to the scene at a random point in time?' If you would be so kind to further explain your solution with the switch case, that would be great!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I will guess you are having problems select random object from array.
Please elaborate your issue so we can provide a better answer.

To get random object from array simply get an object at randomly selected index, like this:

```
id randomObject = [array objectAtIndex:arc4random_uniform(array.count)];
```

Answer (score 0):

Add this For in your viewDidLoad or where you want and replace the values to MAX_X and MAX_Y that you need:

```
for (int i = 0; i < countObjects; i++)
{
    CGPoint position = (CGPoint){(arc4random() % MAX_X) + 1.0f, (arc4random() % MAX_Y) + 1.0f};
    [self createNodeWithPosition:position];
}
```

And add this method:

```
- (void)createNodeWithPosition:(CGPoint)point
{
    SKSpriteNode *box = [[SKSpriteNode alloc] initWithImageNamed:@"image.jpeg"];
    [box setPosition:point];
    [self addChild:box];
}
```